# How to configure Brother DCP-7030 Scanner?

Tags: drivers, wine, emulation, brother, sane

Can I install my scanner drivers through wine, using the windows driver cd packaged with my scanner?

I am using the Brother DCP-7030 Scanner and my system is running Ubuntu 11.10.
I need help to set up scanning.

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on Mac using Virtual Box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not advisable that you use wine to install drivers for any hardware, as they won't be properly integrated into ubuntu.

However here is a step by step guide to get the drivers working (if you're on an 64-bit system):

First unplug your printer.

Open a terminal and copy&paste the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove brother-lpr-drivers-laser brother-cups-wrapper-laser
```

(removes any existing drivers that could cause conflict)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall cups csh lib32stdc++6
```

(reinstalling dependencies)

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/spool/lpd/
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/cups/model/
```

(make directories for the drivers)

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/brother/
cd ~/Downloads/brother/
```

(make download location)

```
wget http://pub.brother.com/pub/com/bsc/linux/dlf/brdcp7030lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.deb
wget http://pub.brother.com/pub/com/bsc/linux/dlf/cupswrapperDCP7030-2.0.2-1.i386.deb
```

(download drivers)

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture brdcp7030lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture cupswrapperDCP7030-2.0.2-1.i386.deb
```

(install and configure driver packages)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/cups/filter/brlpdwrapper* /usr/lib64/cups/filter/
```

(link driver files)

plug in your printer now and proceed with the installation process from 'System Settings' -> 'Printers'

To enable scanning:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sane-utils xsane xsane-common
```

Download Scanner drivers from brother home page (64-bit):
http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan3-0.2.11-4.amd64.deb&lang=English_gpl

(32-bit) 
http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan3-0.2.11-4.i386.deb&lang=English_gpl

plug in and turn on your scanner
open a terminal and type

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all ~/Downloads/brscan3-0.2.11-4.amd64.deb
```

(for 64-bit)

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all ~/Downloads/brscan3-0.2.11-4.i386.deb
```

(for 32-bit)

check if it installed correctly

```
dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother
```

output should look something like this:

```
ii  brdcp7030lpr:i386       2.0.2-1         Brother DCP-7030 LPR driver 
ii  cupswrapperdcp7030:i386       2.0.2-1         Brother DCP7030 CUPS wrapper driver
```

Finally type

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

and at the following text right before this line (pretty far down at the bottom)

'# The following rule will disable USB autosuspend for the device'

Text to add:

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Restart the computer now and it should work.

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/cups/filter/brlpdwrapper* (is it asterix after brlpdwrapper)  /usr/lib64/cups/filter/

Comment: Do I need to remove the scanner drivers as well and reinstall it?

Comment: yes, the asterix means it will affect anything that starts with the words 'brlpdwrapper'

Comment: just updated my answer to include a walkthrough to enable scanning

Comment: thanks..will run through the steps today evening and post the outcome.

Comment: just an fyi--am running Ubuntu 11.10 on Mac using VirtualBox..am assuming the above steps applies to it also.

Comment: yes should be the same. although you might have some problem with the usb ports actually being recognized by the virtualbox

Comment: any solution if it happens

Comment: if you'd run it under ubuntu I could point you to a configuration file to edit....however since it runs under mac it probably works out of the box. If anything happens though this might be your place to ask http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you please let me know which is the configuration file to edit and what should be edited.. just a know how

Comment: for ubuntu versions from 10.04 upward look at the file /etc/udev/rules.d/10-vboxdrv.rules if there's a line looking like this: 'SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ENV{DEVTYPE}==”usb_device”, GROUP=”vboxusers”, MODE=0664' you have to change the mode to '0666' in ubuntu 11.10 with virtualBox 4.1.2 run 'sudo usermod -aG vboxusers <your_username>' (without the brackets around the name)

Comment: Am not able to locate 10-vboxdrv.rules. Also running sudo usermod -aG vboxusers <your_username> provided  usermod: group 'vboxusers' does not exist

Comment: yes, because you are running virtualbox on a mac. As I said, these commands only apply when you are running virtualbox on ubuntu. If I have understood you correctly, you are using MacOS to run ubuntu inside a virtualbox(?) So if the usb port isn't recognized (you can run 'lsusb' in ubuntu and see if anything Brother is detected) you have to change some settings on your mac probably. But I don't know how or what.

Comment: I have some progress..now when I scan any document GIMP Image Editor application starts and message is displayed Opening '/home/viraj/brscan/brscan.D7ycUB' failed:Unknown file type

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2792/discussion-between-daniel-and-viraj-rao)

Comment: Installing `xsane` and `xsane-common` seems to have done the trick for me... I used an installer bash script downloaded from the Brother site, but it seems not to check for this particular dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Did not get the scanner working until I installed the updated driver:

brscan3-0.2.11-5.amd64.deb (and not brscan3-0.2.11-4.amd64.deb)

http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan3-0.2.11-5.amd64.deb&lang=English_gpl

from this page.

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following additionally

```
http://localhost:631
```

Then under CUPS for Administrators, I clicked on 'Adding Printers and Classes'

The rest of the steps are intuitive. 
Please make sure to remove the previously 'installed' Brother-7030 printer if that was set as default previously in System->Administration->Printing.

My Brother 7030 now works fine.

Comment: I just used this guide in 12.04, and now that its finally working the name of the printer in cups manager is Brother_DCP-7030. I also found the way by deleting the instance in settings and letting it configure again once the drivers were installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I mainly asnwering for my next ubuntu reinstall, but maybe I will help someone else. On Brother's page, there is a tool, which automates whole process of installing printer and scanner drivers. This tool is called `Driver Install Tool`, and is available https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp7030_all&os=128#SelectLanguageType-625_0_1 . It will download all deb packages, and apt dependencies (I was fighting without this tool 2 days, and I think problem was missing libusb package). I'm pretty sure, this tool is sufficient to installing other Brother devices as well.