# Brother's scanner is not working on Ubuntu 12.10 32-bits

Tags: 12.10, scanner, brother

I have a brother DCP J125

I have downloaded and installed the scanner driver but Simple Scan shows that it couldn't detect any scanner.

I'm running on **Ubuntu 12.10 32bits**, the steps show in [the Brother FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html) do not work for me as I can't find the lib64 folder.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That link was for 11.10 beta 2.

Comment: This mioght work for your printer too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/113272/how-to-configure-brother-dcp-7030-scanner(assuming printer driver will be a general driver). Where is says to download the driver get the newest one.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect with Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit, even without rebooting

Answer (score 1):

**HOW TO INSTALL PRINTER/SCANNER Brother DCP-J125 DRIVERS ON UBUNTU 12.10 64-BIT / 32-BIT**

INSTALLING PRINTER DRIVER

1. Install 32-bit library - ia32-libs through Ubuntu Software Center.

   Search under "ia32-libs" or "multiarc"

   For 32 bit Ubuntu : Skip step 1 .
2. Download LPdriver dcpj125lpr-1.1.3-1.i386 and cupswrapper dcpj125cupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386 (the debian versions) from

   http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-J125
3. Make directories first

   ```
   sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd

   sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd/dcpj125
   ```
4. Install dcpj125lpr-1.1.3-1.i386 :

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all  dcpj125lpr-1.1.3-1.i386.deb

   For 32 bit Ubuntu : just click to install
   ```
5. Install dcpj125cupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all  dcpj125cupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386.deb

   For 32 bit Ubuntu : just click to install
   ```
6. Turn on printer
7. Add printer in Printing - Brother DCP-J125

INSTALLING SCANNER DRIVER

1. Download brscan3 64bit and scan-key-tool 64 bit (debian versions)
   from

   http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html
2. Click on both files and install them through Ubuntu Software Center
3. Ignore warnings and install.
4. On terminal type:

   ```
     sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
   ```
5. Add the following two lines to the end of the device list.
   (Before the line "# The following rule will disable ..."):
   If there is "LABEL="libsane_rules_end"", add the following 2 lines before "LABEL="libsane_rules_end"".

   The lines to be added :

   ```
     #Brother scanners
     ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
   ```
6. Save and Restart the OS.

Works for Simple Scan, XSane,  sane-pygtk and perhaps others too..

Comment: can you confirm that scanning actually works in 12.10 or higher?