# Brother DCP-7030 with 12.04 - weird error

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, scanner, brother

I have a DCP-7030 that I need to work on a brand-new 12.04 install (running the fallback gnome).

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113272/how-to-configure-brother-dcp-7030-scanner) and then had to go into the cups manager, because the printer was using the wrong driver (DCP 7025), so I chose the right driver.

Then, I printed the test page, it printed perfectly!  However, I have had so much trouble with this Brother printer that I didn't get excited, which was wise.

After printing the test page, it will not print again, the printer gives me an error message of something like, please insert the paper by hand.

Could someone please help?  I have this printer running fine on 10.04 but I can't get it working properly on 12.04...

Comment: Ok I am getting more info as I explore. I thought I had it, I got one page of a document, but then the same error. When I install, it ends up showing the driver is Brother DCP-7025 BR-Script3, and it won't print at all (just Idle-sending data to printer). But then, after i change the driver in the cups manager to the 7030 driver, I got two test pages and two pages of a word doc. but then on re-start, driver is still 7030, but no printing again and weird message about hand feed paper in. Oh there was also an error on the first printing of the doc, but I couldn't catch it in time.

Comment: concerns I have are "sudo aa-complain cupsd" doesn't work, and I don't know what to do about that.  Also, following the linked askubuntu primer on the dcp-7030, I went through all the steps except this one, which didn't work: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/cups/filter/brlpdwrapper* /usr/lib64/cups/filter/ because the file doesn't exist. Also lib32stdc++6 doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the udev rule from the [linked post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113272/how-to-configure-brother-dcp-7030-scanner)

```
sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

And add:

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

I re-installed after pulling out all brother packages in synaptic, I did that before but missed the `printer-driver-ptouch` package which is related to Brother, so this time I deleted that. I also deleted the printer in the settings dialog, I think that was what did it finally.

When I re-installed, I checked and found I did have this file, in both places actually so I didn't need to copy it over:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/cups/filter/brlpdwrapper* /usr/lib64/cups/filter/
```

Good luck to all poor souls dealing with brother printers!  I will leave the scanner installation for later!